# How to log the start and the completion of DB transactions in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, glassfish, log4j

```
sql_show = true
```

this property in hibernate prints the sql that is run, but i want to see the `begin transaction` and `complete transaction` statements as well so that i can track the transaction duration and see the query run in which transaction.

googling reveals that

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG, defaultAppender
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type = DEBUG, defaultAppender
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=DEBUG, defaultAppender
```

should show you the transaction level data as well.
But it doesnt.

Investigating more i looked into hibernate code and found a class name

```
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl
```

this class has the begin and complete method but this method does not log any thing.

***Any advice how to see the transaction level info in hibernate*** ?
I am using hibernate 2.2

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### For Hibernate 5

- For SLF4J logging:

  ```
  <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl" level="debug"/>
  ```
- For Log4j:

  ```
   <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>
  ```

### For Hibernate 4

You need to set the logging threshold to DEBUG for the following classes:

1. For JDBC transactions (e.g. RESOURCE_LOCAL)

   - For SLF4J logging:

     ```
     <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction" level="debug"/>
     ```
   - For Log4j:

     ```
     <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
     </logger>
     ```
2. For JTA transactions

   - For SLF4J logging:

     ```
     <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransaction" level="debug"/>
     ```
   - For Log4j:

     ```
     <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransaction">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
     </logger>
     ```

It's better to activate the DEBUG level for as few classes as possible because otherwise, your logs size will increase dramatically.

Comment: The above logger levels didn't work for me
What worked was: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl

Comment: Thanks. That was written for Hibernate 4 but I updated it for 5 as well.

Comment: If it is not too much asking, could you please update it for Hibernate 3? (And yes, we are still using Hibernate 3 :/)

Answer (score 6):

try to set hibernate generate_statistics property

```
<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
```

and set

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

then you will see all hibernate logs, and you will be able to correctly choose hibernate classes to log in log4j configuration file

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to see transaction isolation level for new created transactions:

log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager=debug
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager=debug
log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=debug
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager=debug

Answer (score 1):

Enabling these logs may be helpful also

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.resource.transaction" level="debug"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.resource.jdbc" level="debug"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl" level="debug"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl" level="debug"/>
```

(hibernate 5)

it prints logs about session begin/close and other relevant details

> [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] (default task-19) Opened Session [8c3ecbac-91b5-4dd8-b012-bfb1b4fe476c] at timestamp: 1592951456170
> .....

> [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] (default task-19) Closing session [8c3ecbac-91b5-4dd8-b012-bfb1b4fe476c] ........
> [org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl] (default task-19) Logical connection closed